# How to parse a JSON containing dynamic keys using decodable?

Tags: ios, swift, decodable

### The problem

I am currently experiencing issues with decoding generic keys in a JSON. My current implementation accepts 3 keys primary, secondary, tertiary. However in the future I want to have the key of JSON dictionaries to be generic. I have tried to implement a similar way as stated in this tutorial: https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/. Unfortunately I can not get it working and some help is really welcome.

### My question ain't no duplicate of the below one

The following post handles a way different level of generic"nes": [How to deal with completely dynamic JSON responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48529651/how-to-deal-with-completely-dynamic-json-responses) therefore my question is a lot more concise than the one that market this question as duplicate with the post above..

#### current JSON

```
{
  "primary": {
    "color": [3,111,66,1],
    "font": {
      "name": "UniversLTStd-UltraCn",
      "size": "16"
    }
  },
  "secondary": {
    "color": [11,34,56,1],
    "font": {
      "name": "UniversLTStd-UltraCn",
      "size": "16"
    }
  },
  "tertiary": {
    "color": [233,222,211,1],
    "font": {
      "name": "UniversLTStd-UltraCn",
      "size": "16"
    }
  }
}
```

#### wished / possible JSON

```
{
      "SomeKey": {
        "color": [3,111,66,1],
        "font": {
          "name": "UniversLTStd-UltraCn",
          "size": "16"
        }
      },
      "OtherKey": {
        "color": [11,34,56,1],
        "font": {
          "name": "UniversLTStd-UltraCn",
          "size": "16"
        }
      },
      "AnotherKey": {
        "color": [233,222,211,1],
        "font": {
          "name": "UniversLTStd-UltraCn",
          "size": "16"
        }
      }
    }
```

The decodable structs can be found here: https://pastebin.com/ZYafkDNH

> ### The question
>
> How can I migrate my current code to accepts dynamic keys (at the place of primary, secondary, tertiary..) so I do not have to hard code them in the Base/Root Struct which can be found in Theme now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with completely dynamic JSON responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48529651/how-to-deal-with-completely-dynamic-json-responses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem to be responsible for the JSON I recommend to change the structure to an array and a `type` property.

```
[{"type": "primary",
  "appearance": {
    "color": [3,111,66,1],
    "font": {
      "name": "UniversLTStd-UltraCn",
      "size": "16"
      }
    }
  },
  {
  "type": "secondary",
  "appearance": {
    "color": [11,34,56,1],
    "font": {
      "name": "UniversLTStd-UltraCn",
      "size": "16"
      }
    }
  },
  {
  "type": "tertiary",
  "appearance": {
    "color": [233,222,211,1],
    "font": {
      "name": "UniversLTStd-UltraCn",
      "size": "16"
      }
    }
}]
```

which is much easier to maintain.

The corresponding structs are

```
struct Theme : Decodable {
    let type : String // could be even a custom enum
    let appearance : Appearance
}

struct Appearance: Decodable {
    let color: [UInt8]
    let font: Font
}

struct Font: Decodable {
    let name, size: String
}
```

and decode the JSON to `[Theme].self`

Otherwise as suggested by Sh_Khan you have to decode a dictionary or you have to write a custom initializer.

Comment: What are the pros and cons of this? Besides that, can you answer the question as well ? :D

Comment: ***Pro*** is better `Codable` compliant. ***Con*** is a dictionary access is faster. Regarding the question please see my added last sentence.

Comment: what we be the structure in swift? (in terms of structs) because after the change I receive the following error: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: please update your answer with valid swift mate. So I can review and accept your answer

Comment: can you review my pastebin in the question? I already have a Style struct which is the exact same as the two Structs Appearance en Font.

Comment: This error I get before even hitting the decoder: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: You can probably use the custom Font and Color decoder as well. And as I said you have to decode `[Theme].self` (array)  not `Theme.self` (dictionary). That's what the error says.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182415/discussion-between-kevin-vugts-and-vadian).

Answer (score 3):

You can try to parse it as a dictionary of `[String:Key]` instead of hardcoding the keys , by that it'll be parsed if keys are changed , but you have to do some logic inside the app to know which value corresponds to a specified key

```
let res = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String:Key].self, from: jsonData)


struct Key: Codable {
    let color: [Int]
    let font: Font
}

struct Font: Codable {
    let name, size: String
}
```